# Store value from a correlation - jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a dropdown list correlation.I have correlated the entire string  and used split() function of jmeter. My correlation value is:

```
temp=<option value="5">CANCELLED</option><option value="1">NEW</option><option value="2">ACTIVE</option><option value="4">TERMINATED</option><option value="6">IN-ACTIVE</option><option value="7
```

Using split() function i have splited the above as following,

```
temp_1=<option value=
temp_10=6
temp_11=>IN-ACTIVE</option><option value=
temp_12=7
temp_2=5
temp_3=>CANCELLED</option><option value=
temp_4=1
temp_5=>NEW</option><option value=
temp_6=2
temp_7=>ACTIVE</option><option value=
temp_8=4
temp_9=>TERMINATED</option><option value=
temp_n=12
```

Now i need to substitute **7** (temp_12 value) in subsequent requests. Each time the list length may vary and so is the temp_n(12) count value.Can anyone please let me know how to save this value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but you will always have the count available as ${temp_n} and the value of temp_12 as ${temp_12}

Comment: my count value ${temp_n} will differ for different input data. Based on the count value, i need to substitute the value of ${temp_n}

Comment: Ah, there are a couple different ways to do this. Easiest would be to write a beanshell script with IF statements to setup your parameters:  IF ${temp_n} = X, then do Y